# Convert hyperlink and bookmarked words to html <a> tag in Word using VBA macros

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word with bookmarked like "[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/)".
How should it be converted to HTML anchor tag using VBA macros

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">click here</a>
```

And then, if a word with bookmarked internal or external, how to convert the text, for e.g., a popup box appears on the word like "t20 CTRL+click to Link"

```html
<a href="t20">Introduction Matthew Davidson</a>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming enthusiasts. The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would like to extract the hyperlinks from text. So I have solved the question with below the code.

```
Sub HlinkChanger()
Dim oRange As Word.Range
Dim oField As Field
Dim link As Variant
With ActiveDocument
.Range.AutoFormat
For Each oRange In .StoryRanges
For Each oFld In oRange.Fields
If oFld.Type = wdFieldHyperlink Then
For Each link In oFld.Result.Hyperlinks
oFld.Select
Selection.InsertBefore "<a href=""" + link.Address + """>"
Selection.InsertAfter "</a>"
Next link
End If
Next oFld
Set oRange = oRange.NextStoryRange
Next oRange
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you for support...