# How to find a hyperlink text and replace with embedded text?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How should I find a hyperlink text and replace with the embedded text for the below examples?

For e.g. 1:

**Table of Contents**

```
<p><a href="ch1">Introduction</a>. It refers to the corresponding id "ch1"/p>
<p><a href="ch2">Research</a>. It refers to the corresponding id "ch2"</p>
<p><a href="ch3">Results</a>. It refers to the corresponding id "ch3"</p>
<p><a href="ch4">Discussion</a>. It refers to the corresponding id "ch4"</p>
<p><a href="ch5">Conclusion</a>. It refers to the corresponding id "ch5"</p>
```

E.g. 2:

```
www.google.com
www.stackoverflow.com
```

E.g. 3:

**Citations**

```
*see* <a href="ch1">Chapter. 1</a>. It refers to the id "ch1"
*see* <a href="fig1">Fig. 1</a>. It refers to the id "fig1"
*see* <a href="tab1">Table. 1</a>. It refers to the id "tab1"
```

The above mentioned examples are converted to html `<a>` tag using VBA Macros.

Example 1 should be converted to:

```
     <a href="ch1">Introduction<a>
     <a href="ch2">Research</a>
     <a href="ch3">Results</a>
     <a href="ch4">Discussion</a>
     <a href="ch5">Conclusion</a>
```

E.g. 2 should be converted to:

```
   <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
   <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

E.g. 2 should be converted to:

```
   <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
   <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert hyperlink and bookmarked words to html <a> tag in Word using VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600076/convert-hyperlink-and-bookmarked-words-to-html-a-tag-in-word-using-vba-macros)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would like to extract the hyperlinks from text. So I have solved the  question with below the code.

```
    Sub HlinkChanger()
Dim oRange As Word.Range
Dim oField As Field
Dim link As Variant
With ActiveDocument
.Range.AutoFormat
For Each oRange In .StoryRanges
For Each oFld In oRange.Fields
If oFld.Type = wdFieldHyperlink Then
For Each link In oFld.Result.Hyperlinks
oFld.Select
Selection.InsertBefore "<a href=""" + link.Address + """>"
Selection.InsertAfter "</a>"
Next link
End If
Next oFld
Set oRange = oRange.NextStoryRange
Next oRange
End With
End Sub
```